# R glmer.nb output. How to get $\hat{\theta}$?

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, negative-binomial-distribution

I would like to obtain estimated $\theta$ from glmer.nb function in lme4 package. In my understanding this function fits the model:
$$
Y_{ij}|\boldsymbol{B}_{i}=\boldsymbol{b}_i \overset{ind.}{\sim} NB\Big(mean=\mu,var=\mu + \frac{\mu^2}{\theta}\Big)
$$
where $NB$ refers to the negative binomial distribution and:
$$
\mu = \exp(\boldsymbol{X}_{ij}^T \boldsymbol{\beta} + \boldsymbol{Z}_{ij}^T \boldsymbol{b}_i)
$$
and 
$$
\boldsymbol{B}_i \overset{i.i.d.}{\sim} MVN(mean=\boldsymbol{0},var=\Sigma).
$$
So glmer.nb must be estimating unknown parameters $\boldsymbol{\beta}$, $\Sigma$ and $\theta$ via maximizing its likelihood. The help file of glmer.nb little explains its functionality, and it says "glmer() for Negative Binomial". However, the negative binomial is NOT an exponential family when the parameter $\theta$ is unknown. So $\theta$ must be estimated in some other ways that generalized linear mixed effect models (GLMM) do not take, and the estimated $\theta$ must be obtained in some special ways that GLMM do not take. How can I access to the estimate of $\theta$ which should be one of glmer.nb output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the source code, this isn't something that is trivially exposed. Essentially, `glmer.nb` is (from [github sources](https://github.com/lme4/lme4/blob/609055aa9e7c0215653359e7b7f818ce1de3b762/R/nbinom.R)):

```
glmer.nb <- function(..., interval = log(th)+c(-3,3), verbose=FALSE)
{
  g0 <- glmer(..., family=poisson)
  th <- est_theta(g0)
  if(verbose) cat("th := est_theta(glmer(..)) =", format(th),"\n")
  g1 <- update(g0, family = negative.binomial(theta=th))
  ## if (is.null(interval)) interval <- log(th)+c(-3,3)
  optTheta(g1, interval=interval, verbose=verbose)
}
```

Which essentially is:

1. fit a standard Poisson GLMM
2. estimate $\theta$ using maximum likelihood estimation given this standard Poisson fit. This uses `MASS::theta.ml()`
3. refit the model using this value of $\theta$ and the `negative.binomial()` family function which needs a fixed $\theta$,
4. <strike>last line does an optimization to find $\theta$ given the updated fit, and that function throws an error if the original estimate from 2. and the optimised one from 4. don't match.</strike>

   the last line performs 1-d optimisation on the interval `log(theta) + c(-3, 3)` via `optimize()` to find the value of $\theta$ that minimises the deviance of the negative binomial GLMM.

That said, you might try:

```
lme4:::getNBdisp(fit)
```

where `fit` is the model returned by `glmer.nb`. This is just a guess based on reading the code but it is used by the authors in tests etc.

Comment: Thank you very much for reading the source code. I understand that this algorithm is iteratively maximizing ($\Sigma$,$\beta$), and then $\theta$, twice to find MLE. It is interesting and surprising for me that two iterations are enough to find the maximum likelihood estimates.

Comment: It isn't doing just two iterations. The first estimate in 2 is derived using maximum likelihood via the `theta.ml` function from the [MASS](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/MASS/html/theta.md.html) package, given information from the Poisson fit in 1. It then refits a negative binomial model with this theta fixed. In 4 I was mistaken: what is done is a 1d optimization for theta by minimizing the deviance of the fitted NB GLMM.

Comment: I see now what is being done; the first couple of lines get you close to the MLE of $\theta$ and a NB GLMM is fitted using this, then 4 homes in on best theta by trying all values of theta around  +/- the initial estimate to find one that gives minimum deviance.